# Get length of contents inside iframe and modify display based on result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to write some jQuery code to get the content length on an element whose id="newUp" from an iframe, and if length == 0 then show the element whose class="OE" from the page:

```
function onframeload(){
if($( "iframe:contains('.new')" ).length > 0){
    $('.oe').show()
}
};
```

I am a beginner in javascript.

Main page code is:

```
<div style="display:none;" class="oe">CHAL PEA OE!</div>

<iframe onload="onframeload();" src="//jsfiddle.net/ROYALRandhawa/Lysn9e5z/embedded/result/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is the code in the iframe:

```
<div class="news"><center>Welcome Boss</center></div>
<span id="newUp">Here is new update</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a security mechanism in browsers that prevents you from performing tasks in the iframes that doen't belong to the same domain

Take a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Brother please suggest me something to do that task, I am in trouble I have to submit a project before deadline please help me.